# Gluing fusama paper

Tags: doors

I have imported fusama panels consisting of paper laminated to silk with a design printed on the silk. I tried gluing them to the doors and although we had it perfectly smooth as it cured the silk upper layer developed big bubbles and air pockets.
No idea how to proceed with the next try.

Comment: Did you use wall paper glue, in a very light coat on the door itself?  How large was the doors, full size.  How did you apply the glue?  Appears you used a very wet glue that lifted the silk off the paper.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the fixing method to avoid glue.

I suggest that you consider using a method of clamping the panels into place.

If the new panel is used to cover the old surface or panel of the door then a fixing trim around the edge may be sufficient. If the old panel is to be removed so the new one is to be visible from both sides then two bits of trim will be needed.